# Data table inserting records again and again

Tags: c#, sql, database, parsing, html-agility-pack

i am getting links with Html agility pack but my Data Table is inserting links again and again don't know why i think there i some kind of problem with my Data Table condition or what.
here is code

```
public DataTable GetCategories()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select ID,Link from Try where Type='Categories'", obj.openConnection());
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
```

here i am getting categories which has data ID Name Link Type and here is my Data table which is inserting records again and again into database

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = cc.GetCategories();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    res.GetSubCategories(dt.Rows[i]["Link"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));

                }
            }
```

help me how to prevent it to insert same record again and again

Comment: I can't see an insert here? you're just retrieving data from database

Comment: sorry, i guess i am having a problem in my agility pack code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a problem with the loops in your agility pack i have also had this kind of error when i was new. Try writing your code again and change the logic in your agility pack because i guess it's retrieving all records again and again in your code and there in no problem with your Data table

Comment: Thanks but i solved it earlier yeah you are right mate,was having problem with my code